# Преобразование типов

Tags: php

Всем привет, я начал заниматся php и в уроке сказано, что при таком коде:

```
$sum=(double)4;
```

вместо вывода целого числа должна появится дробь 4.0. Но у меня как было 4, так и осталось. Это значит, что я ошибся или так и должно быть?

Answer (score 3):

В примере все в порядке, если сделать `var_dump($sum);` то мы увидим, что там, действительно, `float(4)`. Другое дело, что `echo` выводит в «человекочитаемом» формате, и выводит просто четверку.

Из-за слабой типизации все практические различия будут касаться, пожалуй, только внутреннего представления данных в памяти, «под капотом» и поведения функций `is_int()` и `is_float()` (`is_double()`). Все равно PHP в большинстве случаев будет пытаться привести типы автоматически, и, если что, например, сам переделает int в float никого не спрашивая.

Ручное приведение типов будет иметь смысл, например, в случаях, когда Вы взаимодействуете с какой-то строго типизированной системой (например, веб-сервисом), которая требует строго определенных типов данных (и откажется принимать `4` вместо `4.0`). Но подобное — относительно редкая ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Книга у вас странная, так и должно быть. 
ЗЫ: типов в пхп как таковых нет, это не типизированный ЯП. Поэтому пока не стоит заморачиватся наж этим. Со временем всё поймется.

Comment: Типы в PHP есть, просто php относится к динамически и слаботипизированным языкам. Соответственно приведение типов происходит на каждый чих (и может вызывать довольно странные вещи).

А еще есть костыль [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) для этакой своеобразной строгой типизации. Но это или когда кроме PHP нет ни одного языка или на любителя тонких извращений.

Comment: Ооок, если типы есть, то согласитесь что операции над этими типами должны им соответствовать. Правильно я говорю ?

а теперь выполните команду: 

`var_dump("044" == "44");` 

и подумайте над результатом.

я сравниваю 2 переменные типа string, и логично что ответ должен быть false.

Comment: @shurik, существование приведения типов может только подтверждать существование типов, а не их отсутствие. Нетипизированные языки — это большинство ассемблеров или некоторые Форты — языки, где нет понятия «тип» вообще как такового, но никак не PHP, где понятие типа строго определено. Если бы Вы просто сказали что PHP нетипизированный — вопрос был бы терминологический (есть такое дело, да), но Вы сказали что «типов как таковых нет.» А это уже неправда.

А то, что `==` бесполезен — это традиционное доказательство кривокостыльности PHP, но никак не отсутствия у него типов.